# Why does lsblk show multiple mount versions of snapd and core20?

Tags: mount, snap

lsblk shows:

```
loop1    7:1    0  59.1M  1 loop /snap/core20/1782
loop2    7:2    0  59.1M  1 loop /snap/core20/1826
loop3    7:3    0  43.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17954
loop4    7:4    0  43.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18363
```

I understand that these exist in the relevant directory structure each with a soft link for "current" pointing to the latest version - but can I prevent the older one from being mounted? Alternatively, can I delete the /snap/core20/1782 and snap/snapd/17954 directories?

Comment: They don't use up any [additional] disk space; other than appearing in some of your commands (*distracting you from what you are actually looking for*) so removing them just reduces features & doesn't save anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

@guiverc @FedKad OK - Thanks - all three comments help to assist understanding this. Since it is part of the design I'll learn to live with it - but would have thought it would be enough to mount the "current" snap. I am going through a process of cleaning up after removing qemu-kvm which failed to remove "cleanly" and just wanted to be sure nothing was going to impact on lxd install